# how to handle WM_NCHITTEST in a naked event loop?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm playing with Windows API trying to understand how it behaves, and I realized that I can remove WNDPROC altogether and handle things with a naked event loop, like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

static struct {
    HWND desktop;
    HWND window;
} global;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* anonymous scope: register window class */
    {
        WNDCLASSEXW wcx;
        wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
        wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcx.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
        wcx.cbClsExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOWFRAME;
        wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wcx.lpszClassName = L"MyWindow";
        wcx.hIconSm = wcx.hIcon;
        RegisterClassExW(&wcx);
    }

    global.desktop = GetDesktopWindow();

    global.window = CreateWindowExW (
        0,
        L"MyWindow",
        NULL,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0,
        0,
        320,
        200,
        global.desktop,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    /* anonymous scope, event loop */
    {
        MSG msg;

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.hwnd == global.window) {
                if (msg.message == WM_PAINT) {
                    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                    HDC hdc;

                    hdc = BeginPaint(msg.hwnd, &ps);

                    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
                    Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 320, 200);

                    EndPaint(msg.hwnd, &ps);
                } else {
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            } else {
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }    
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to go one step further and try making this window moveable using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773941/2012715) technique, and got confused because I can't "return" from a message loop in the way i'm used to(the statement `return hit;`) does not make sense in this context.

Here is how I started, and got confused:

```
#include <Windows.h>

static struct {
    HWND desktop;
    HWND window;
} global;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* anonymous scope: register window class */
    {
        WNDCLASSEXW wcx;
        wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
        wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcx.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
        wcx.cbClsExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOWFRAME;
        wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wcx.lpszClassName = L"MyWindow";
        wcx.hIconSm = wcx.hIcon;
        RegisterClassExW(&wcx);
    }

    global.desktop = GetDesktopWindow();

    global.window = CreateWindowExW (
        0,
        L"MyWindow",
        NULL,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0,
        0,
        320,
        200,
        global.desktop,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    /* anonymous scope, event loop */
    {
        MSG msg;

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.hwnd == global.window) {
                if (msg.message == WM_PAINT) {
                    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                    HDC hdc;

                    hdc = BeginPaint(msg.hwnd, &ps);

                    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
                    Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 320, 200);

                    EndPaint(msg.hwnd, &ps);
                } else if (msg.message == WM_NCHITTEST) {
                    LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(msg.hwnd, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
                    if (hit == HTCLIENT) {
                        hit = HTCAPTION;
                    }
                    // return hit; // makes no sense here
                } else {
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            } else {
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }    
    }


    return 0;
}
```

How can I simulate returning "hit" from the WM_NCHITTEST condition so that it moves the window like in the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773941/2012715 ?

PS: I know that it's better to use a map(like std::unordered_map) rather than a long if/switch for scalability and readability, but I wanted to keep the example more direct.

Comment: To downvoters: if you downvote you should explain why, else it's pointless. The question is quite understandable and even has a MCVE so I really don't see a reason for downvote.

Comment: @zett42: This question is asking about problems caused by randomly changing code, the OP doesn't understand. This is hardly useful to the general public, that tends to want to solve real problems, rather than artificial ones. The useful question the OP *should* have asked instead: *"What is the purpose of [DispatchMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934.aspx)?"* As asked, this question isn't useful.

Comment: randomly changing code I don&amp;#39;t understand? I was confused about how NCHITTEST was sent to the window. It turns out to be seen by the window proc, but not the thread message queue; it is useful to understand how this occurs(some messages like WM_PAINT, and WM_MOUSEMOVE get seen by the thread message queue, while NCHITTEST is not). I don't understand your concern.

Comment: It stands to reason, that you do not understand the consequences of registering a window procedure, because you do not understand [message routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#routing) in a Windows application. All of this is documented and readily available. A question asking how to best fight the system is not generally useful.

Comment: I understand the consequences of registering a window procedure. I didn't understand the concept of queued and non queued messages. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can't.

The code you have shown will NEVER work, because `(Get|Peek)Message()` returns only [**QUEUED**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#quequed_messages) messages.  You cannot reply to a queued message, because the sender is not waiting for a reply, it put the message in the queue and moved on to other things.  Only [**NON-QUEUED**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#nonqueued_messages) messages that are sent with the `SendMessage...()` family of functions can be replied to.  `(Get|Peek)Message()` will NEVER return a sent message, but will internally dispatch it to the target window's message procedure (only messages sent from another thread will be dispatched, messages sent to a window by the same thread that owns the window will bypass the message queue completely).

`WM_PAINT` is a queued message, so your event loop sees it.  But `WM_NCHITTEST` is not queued, so your message loop will NEVER see it directly, it can only be seen in a message procedure.

What you have shown is NOT the right way to handle a Windows UI message loop.  Since you are creating a UI window, you MUST provide it with a message procedure (if not by `RegisterClass/Ex()`, then by `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()`).  But DO NOT use `DefWindowProc()` for that procedure if you need to process messages manually.  Provide your own message procedure that calls `DefWindowProc()` (or `CallWindowProc()` in the case of `GWL_WNDPROC`, or `DefSubclassProc()` in the case of `SetWindowSubclass()`) for any unhandled messages, eg:

```
LRESULT WINAPI MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
            Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 320, 200);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_NCHITTEST: {
            LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            if (hit == HTCLIENT) {
                hit = HTCAPTION;
            }
            return hit;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* anonymous scope: register window class */
    {
        WNDCLASSEXW wcx;
        wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
        wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcx.lpfnWndProc = MyWndProc; // <--
        wcx.cbClsExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void *);
        wcx.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOWFRAME;
        wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wcx.lpszClassName = L"MyWindow";
        wcx.hIconSm = wcx.hIcon;
        RegisterClassExW(&wcx);
    }

    global.desktop = GetDesktopWindow();

    global.window = CreateWindowExW (
        0,
        L"MyWindow",
        NULL,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0,
        0,
        320,
        200,
        global.desktop,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    /* anonymous scope, event loop */
    {
        MSG msg;

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that I can easily do this in a callback. I was just curious if there was a way to handle NCHITTEST in this way. It appears that even with the callback, to my surprise, the loop itself never receives WM_NCHITTEST message. It seems like WndProc gets the message before the message loop does, so I was thinking about it backwards. This kind of also explains why if STATIC windows don't get many of the events other windows do, its' default proc consumes them before the loop gets to see them, my window is just generous enough to pass them over for the loop to see.

Comment: I'm still not sure why my proc never passes NCHITTEST for the loop to see, is there really no way to expose it? Why is MOUSEMOVE seen by the loop, but NCHITTEST isn't?

Comment: @Dmitry: As I explained in my answer, `WM_NCHITTEST` is NOT a queued message, it does not go through the message queue, so a message loop will never see it. `WM_MOUSMOVE`, on the other hand, IS a queued message, so it goes through the message queue and will be seen by a message loop. Please read the links in my answer, they explain this difference. Things the OS (or other sender) depends on a reply to are NOT queued. Notifications and other things not dependant on a reply are usually queued instead.

Comment: oh so some messages are queued while others are sent directly via CallWindowProc rather than SendMessage?

Comment: @Dmitry: you are mixing apples and oranges. `SendMessage()` and `CallWindowProc()` are very different things for different purposes. Seems you need to do some research on how Windows' messaging systems actually work, what the different component are, and what roles they serve. MSDN has very detailed documentation on this subject.

Comment: would it be fair to say that the main job of WndProc is to handle non queued messages, as these are  the ones that you can't override without subclassing the window?

Comment: @Dmitry the main job of a `WndProc` is to handle ALL messages for a window, whether they are queued or not. Queued messages arrive in the message queue and get dispatched to appropriate windows. Non-queued messages get sent directly to appropriate windows. Either way, all messages for a given window go through the window's `WndProc` for processing.

Comment: An interesting observation is that without DispatchMessage, SendMessage message is always seen by the thread's message queue, but never the WndProc(kinda like X11's event loop); whereas PostMessage is always seen by WndProc but never seen by thread message queue. What's strange is that if WndProc doesn't call DefWindowProc, thread's message queue still sees the WM_PAINT message. WM_NCHITTEST is received by WndProc before thread, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN is seen by thread before WndProc, and depriving this message(161) prevents wndproc from responding to mouse beyond WM_NCHITTEST. very confusing.

Comment: it seems like all messages other than WM_NCHITTEST get handled by the loop which dispatches them to the correct WndProc via a HWND -> WNDPROC map, which seems to contradict all messages being seen by WndProc before the loop.

Comment: @Dmitry: `SendMessage()` messages are NEVER seen by a message loop, but `(Peek|Get)Message()` will dispatch them to the `WndProc` if they are sent from another thread. `PostMessage()` messages require the message loop to call `DispatchMessage()` in order for them to reach the `WndProc`. `WM_PAINT` is generated by `(Peek|Get)Message()` only when there are no other messages in the message queue. All of this is documented on MSDN.