# How to release dragging a window when WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN is fired?

Tags: c++, winapi

I removed the caption of my GUI and created a custom one, when the area is clicked i call `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` to move the GUI, however, there's an area of the caption that i want to avoid dragging the GUI when clicked.

I tried sending `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` , `WM_LBUTTONUP` but the GUI continues being dragged until i release the mouse, how i could cancel the drag when needed?

Comment: Just don't start dragging at all when you get the mouse-down event.  This in general is better done with WM_NCHITTEST, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773941/17034).  Check the lParam

Answer (score -1):

After about 5 minutes searching for how to achieve the thing that you want.

Try making a boolean that is called dragWindow, then try using this code instead of the one that you are working on it.

in the windows procedural

```
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
     dragWindow = true;
     SetCapture(hWnd);
     break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
     ReleaseCapture();
     dragWindow = false;
     break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
     if (dragWindow == true)
     {
         RECT mainWindowRect;
         POINT pos;
         int windowWidth, windowHeight;
 
         pos.x = (int)(short) LOWORD(lParam);
         pos.y = (int)(short) HIWORD(lParam);
 
         GetWindowRect(hWnd,&mainWindowRect);
         windowHeight = mainWindowRect.bottom - mainWindowRect.top;
         windowWidth = mainWindowRect.right - mainWindowRect.left;
 
         ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pos);
         MoveWindow(hWnd, pos.x, pos.y, windowWidth, windowHeight, TRUE);
     }
     break;
```

Found this code in [here](https://codingmisadventures.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/dragging-or-moving-a-window-using-mouse-win32/)!

Edit: Make sure you are releasing the capture of the HWND!

Comment: Sure, the Internet is where you'll easily find loads of garbage code. This being no exception. Just handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message and return `HTCAPTION` for those areas that should allow the window to be dragged. The system does the rest for you (like actually moving the window).